# Why aren't my case fans spinning?

Tags: motherboard, fan, cooling, case, chassis

I have an [ASUS P6T WS Professional](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6T_WS_Professional/) motherboard mounted in a [Thermaltake Armor+](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Chassis/Discontinued_/ARMOR/C_00000091/Armor_/design.htm) case. The case has a fan on the front of the chassis that is functioning, but the rear fan behind the CPU heatsink (the red fan in the picture) and the transparent case side fan do not spin up. When I load the BIOS to look at the power configuration, it does not detect additional chassis fans. I have looked at the manual for both the motherboard and the case, cleaned both fans, and checked the wiring, and cannot figure out why these aren't running. I should note that the blue LED lights around the fan on the side of the case are lighting up.

BIOS "Power" screen:

[image: BIOS Power]

Case configuration:

[image: Case]

ASUS utilities for this motherboard model are not available for my operating system (Windows 8.1). How can I figure out why these fans aren't running?

Comment: are the fans hooked to the board, or the powersupply? only items attached to the board can be detected in the BIOS and the ASUS software. try disabling QFan Control, or selecting a more aggressive profile. N/A may mean "fan not running" rather than "fan not present".

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks, I just discovered that nothing is plugged into the chassis fan connectors on the motherboard.

Comment: Fans can go bad. Have you verified the fans actually work and are not defective? You can do this by attaching them at the point of the one fan that is working. If they do not spin, replace them.